# Python - Inheritance from a Tk class

Tags: python, inheritance, tkinter

I'm trying to create a modular class ( for some gui buttons ).
`CoreButton` should consist of most methods for a common button, including tk frame.

Goal is to inheret `CoreButton`  - and to use its frame to build rest of button's GUI - it does not appear.

any help will be appriciated

```
class CoreButton(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master,nickname, hw_in=[], hw_out=[],ip_in='', ip_out='', sched_vector=[]):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        if ip_in == '': ip_in = ip_out  # in case remote input is not defined

        self.grid()
     #####Rest of code
```

and class that inherits:

```
class ToggleBut2(CoreButton):
    def __init__(self, master, hw_in=[], hw_out=[],ip_in='', ip_out='', sched_vector=[]):
        CoreButton.__init__(self, master, nickname="JOHM", hw_in=hw_in, hw_out=hw_out, ip_in=ip_in, ip_out=ip_out, sched_vector=sched_vector)
        self.master = master

    def build_gui(self, nickname='babe', height=3, width=13):

        self.button = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=nickname, variable=self.but_var, indicatoron=0, height=height, width=width, command=self.sf_button_press)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to create a reusable component that calls `self.grid` -- it limits the reuse only to parent/master widgets that use `grid`.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you call `build_gui`.

Comment: Can you explain why is bad idea

Comment: I did in my comment: it limits the reuse only to parent/master widgets that use `grid`. You can't use it if the parent is  using `pack` or `place`, or trying to place the widget in a text or canvas widget. It tightly couples the widget to the implementation of the code that creates it.

Comment: you don't need `self.master = master` because `Frame` already does it.

Comment: if you use argument `hw_in=[]` then you can get strange result because `[]` is created only once, at program start, not when you create new widget. So all widgets will use the same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you try to do but I would do something like this

I don't use `self.grid()` inside class, so outside class I can use `tb1.pack()` or `tb1.grid()` depends on which layout manager I use in window.

In `__init__` I execute `self.build_gui()` so I don't have to do it manually, but now all classes have to create `self.build_gui()` without arguments.

I add `Label` only for test - to display "selected"/"not selected". You don't need it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class CoreButton(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, nickname, hw_in=None, hw_out=None, ip_in=None, ip_out=None, sched_vector=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.nickname = nickname

        self.hw_in = hw_in
        if self.hw_in is None:
            self.hw_in = []

        #self.hw_in = hw_in or []

        self.hw_out = hw_out
        if self.hw_out is None:
            self.hw_out = []

        #self.hw_out = hw_out or []

        self.ip_out = ip_out
        self.ip_in = ip_in
        if self.ip_in is None:
            self.ip_in = self.ip_out  # in case remote input is not defined

        #self.ip_in = hw_in or self.ip_out

        self.sched_vector = sched_vector
        if sched_vector is None:
            sched_vector = []

        #self.sched_vector = sched_vector or []

        self.build_gui() # <--- to build it automatically

    def build_gui(self):
        # you will overide it in child widgets
        raise NotImplementedError('You have to override method build_gui()')


class ToggleBut2(CoreButton):

    def __init__(self, master, hw_in=None, hw_out=None, ip_in=None, ip_out=None, sched_vector=None, height=3, width=13):

        self.height = height
        self.width = width

        # `self.but_var` is used in `build_gui` so it has to be created before `__init__` which executes `build_gui`
        # or create it directly in `build_gui`
        #self.but_var = tk.StringVar()

        CoreButton.__init__(self, master, "JOHM", hw_in, hw_out, ip_in, ip_out, sched_vector)


    def build_gui(self, nickname='babe'):
        self.but_var = tk.IntVar()

        self.button = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=self.nickname, variable=self.but_var, indicatoron=0, height=self.height, width=self.width, command=self.sf_button_press)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='[not selected]')
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0)


    def sf_button_press(self):
        print(self.but_var.get())
        if self.but_var.get() == 0:
            self.label['text'] = '[ not selected ]'
        else:
            self.label['text'] = '[  selected  ]'

# --- main ---


root = tk.Tk()

tb1 = ToggleBut2(root, height=1, width=10)
tb1.pack()

tb2 = ToggleBut2(root, height=3, width=30)
tb2.pack()

tb2 = ToggleBut2(root, height=5, width=50)
tb2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]